# ASP.NET MVC Html.RenderPartial giving UriFormatException (string too long)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

We have a Controller Action that takes no parameters, it's as simple as:

> www.mysite.com/myController/myAction

When called, this loads a Model.  The Model is essentially a glorified list of objects.  Most of the time it displays perfectly well, but when the number of list items goes over some limit we get a UriFormatException (Uri string is too long).

But, the odd thing is that this then occurs when it attempts to render the **first** item.

In more detail.

The model is passed to a Razor View that displays details about the list.  This View then has a "foreach" loop that calls a partial view via Html.RenderPartial(....).  It's when executing this on the first item that we get the exception.

The actual line that throws the exception within that partial view is:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction(MVC.MyOtherController.ActionNames.AnActionName,
       MVC.MyOtherController.Name, 
       new { someParms = someValues});
}
```

So, this is attempting to call another Controller Action method, and the Uri appears to be too long.